# Read text file only for certain rows to split up file in Python

Tags: python, numpy, text-files

I am loading a text file using np.loadtxt and would like to have python split it up in four. 
Usually I would just copy paste each set of data into different text files and do np.loadtxt for each text file, but I'm going to have to do this hundreds of times so it would be way too time consuming.

Here is a shortened version of the text file. 
So what I'd like to do is to have python read the first number (0.6999) and discard it, then read the 5 following rows of values and assign variable names to each column, and then the next 5 rows with variables to each column again, and so on.

> Is there any way I could tell python to maybe do np.loadtext only for row 1, then only for row 2 to 6, then 7 to 12 etc?

```
   0.699999988
   1    0.2000    0.0618
   2    0.2500    0.0417
   3    0.3000    0.0371
   4    0.3500    0.0390
   5    0.4500    0.0761
    670.0000  169.4000 6.708E-09
    635.0001  169.1806 1.584E-08
    612.9515  168.6255 2.724E-08
    591.2781  168.2719 4.647E-08
  670.00  0.0E+00  0.0E+00  0.0E+00  0.0E+00  0.0E+00  0.0E+00  0.0E+00
  635.00  9.8E-07  4.2E-07  2.1E-07  1.2E-07  4.4E-08  1.8E-08  1.4E-08
  612.95  6.0E-06  3.5E-06  2.1E-06  1.3E-06  4.7E-07  1.8E-07  1.4E-07
  591.28  2.2E-05  1.3E-05  7.7E-06  4.9E-06  1.8E-06  6.6E-07  5.0E-07
  569.98  8.3E-05  5.0E-05  2.8E-05  1.8E-05  6.4E-06  2.4E-06  1.8E-06
  549.06  3.0E-04  1.8E-04  1.0E-04  6.2E-05  2.3E-05  8.4E-06  6.4E-06
  528.51  7.8E-04  5.0E-04  2.8E-04  1.7E-04  6.2E-05  2.3E-05  1.8E-05
  508.34  1.6E-03  1.0E-03  5.8E-04  3.4E-04  1.3E-04  4.9E-05  3.7E-05
```

Here is what I was using for my three different text files:

```
altvall,T,Pp= np.loadtxt('file1.txt',usecols = (0,1,2),unpack=True) # load text file

tau1,tau2,tau3,tau4,tau5,tau6,tau7 = np.loadtxt('file2.txt',usecols = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7),unpack=True) # load text file

wvln,alb = np.loadtxt('file3.txt',usecols = (1,2),unpack=True) # load text file
```

Now I just want something similar but without splitting my text file into different parts.

Comment: Do you have control over how the text file is/was generated?  If so, then using [`numpy.savez`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) instead of `numpy.savetxt` could solve this easily.

Comment: I was just using np.loadtxt for each text file, I didn't hear about np.savez or np.savetxt. Is it also a load text kind of command?

Comment: (And no I don't have control over how it is generated although it is always the same number of lines and columns for each set of data)

Comment: `numpy.savez` allows you to save multiple arrays to one file and load them by a name or keyword using `numpy.load`.  But since you don't have control over generating the input file, don't worry about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use `itertools.izip_longest` to group the rows of your input file into groups of 5.  The key is to do the following:

```
for rows in izip_longest(*[file_object]*N):
    # rows will be a tuple of N consecutive rows
    # do something with rows
```

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import izip_longest

data = []
with open(filehandle, 'r') as fin:
    fin.next() # skip first line
    for rows in izip_longest(*[fin]*5): # read fin 5 rows at a time
        rows = [map(float, r.strip().split()) for r in rows]
        data.append(np.array(rows))
```

This yields a list of 5xN arrays:

```
>>> print data
[array([[ 1.    ,  0.2   ,  0.0618],
       [ 2.    ,  0.25  ,  0.0417],
       [ 3.    ,  0.3   ,  0.0371],
       [ 4.    ,  0.35  ,  0.039 ],
       [ 5.    ,  0.45  ,  0.0761]]),
 array([[  6.70000000e+02,   1.69400000e+02,   6.70800000e-09],
       [  6.35000100e+02,   1.69180600e+02,   1.58400000e-08],
       [  6.12951500e+02,   1.68625500e+02,   2.72400000e-08],
       [  5.91278100e+02,   1.68271900e+02,   4.64700000e-08],
       [  5.69980100e+02,   1.68055300e+02,   7.85900000e-08]]),
 array([[  6.70000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  6.35000000e+02,   9.80000000e-07,   4.20000000e-07,
          2.10000000e-07,   1.20000000e-07,   4.40000000e-08,
          1.80000000e-08,   1.40000000e-08],
       [  6.12950000e+02,   6.00000000e-06,   3.50000000e-06,
          2.10000000e-06,   1.30000000e-06,   4.70000000e-07,
          1.80000000e-07,   1.40000000e-07],
       [  5.91280000e+02,   2.20000000e-05,   1.30000000e-05,
          7.70000000e-06,   4.90000000e-06,   1.80000000e-06,
          6.60000000e-07,   5.00000000e-07],
       [  5.69980000e+02,   8.30000000e-05,   5.00000000e-05,
          2.80000000e-05,   1.80000000e-05,   6.40000000e-06,
          2.40000000e-06,   1.80000000e-06]])]
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it is my fault that it looks like it is only 5 rows for each data set. In the actual text file, the first set is 21 rows, then the second one is about 40, then third, fourth, and fifth sets are about 30 rows each. I will edit my post. Is there maybe an easy way to fix this for a non constant number of rows in your method?

Comment: Will consecutive 'datasets' ever have the same number of columns?

Comment: Yes, each data set always has the same fixed number of columns and rows

Comment: No I am asking whether it will ever be the case that dataset 5 is Nx3 and that dataset 6 is Mx3.  If consecutive datasets can have the same number of columns, that makes this tricky.

Comment: Oh I see, data sets 3, 4 and 5 have the exact same number of columns and rows. But, each of them start with the same number (670.0) in column 1 row 1 and end with the same number in last column last row (0.0).

Comment: Does __every__ dataset start with 670.0?

Comment: No, only the datasets 3, 4 and 5 (the ones which have the exact same number of rows and columns). The datasets 1 and 2 have different number of rows and columns and start with different numbers.